# Cannot read property 'left' of undefined - pagination not working on store

Tags: magento-1.9

Pagination is not working on store page. Checked all settings but very weird
when you go to http://www.longclothing.com/store/ at bottom go to 2nd page. You are still staying at first page but URL is http://www.longclothing.com/store/?p=2 so the pagination is not working.

I tried to change in catalog to show 500 products and it shows me all products. If I revert to show only 64 and have 1,2,3 pages and click on 2nd or 3rd or show all nothing happen.

In chrome console you can see some JS error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Comment: curently 5000 item per page you set , can you set 64 so we can see the pagination

Comment: there is just 64 and 3 pages option.